# images optimization in laravel application

Tags: php, image, optimization, laravel-5

I have a laravel web application with more than thousands of uploaded images in it. I have not optimized my images before and now I have to do the optimization.

now I have two questions about image optimization;

1. I have problem with image optimization. I have tried any packages
   that would do the 'image optimization' but after running my
   optimization code, no changes would apply to the images in my source
   control. **why the package does not change the images?**
2. I am using same images with different sizes in my application.
   forexample an image named "image_1.png" is using with the size
   120*60 pxs in home page and also it is using in another page with
   size 300*150 pxs. **what should I do for these images that are using
   with different sizes for optimization?**

packages that I have used are these:

1. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-image-optimizer.git
2. https://github.com/psliwa/image-optimizer.git

I am using the code like this for my images in database:

```
 foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filePath = //the image path
            ImageOptimizer::optimize($filePath);
        }
```

The above code successfully passes and no errors happen during the code running. but the images does not change.

Comment: is there really any reason to optimize the images? you said you suddenly have to do image optimization is there any specific reason?

Comment: yeah surely for my pagespeed in google(https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) I need to optimize images

Comment: at what dimensions are you serving your images? and are you serving 100 images in one page without using any pagination or lazy loading? also if ur images are already small theres not much optimizing to do unless you are serving extremely high quality images..

Comment: all of my pages have pagination as well. about 10-20 images would be shown in each page. Imagine that I am showing a list of users in a page with their images in little dimention (forexample 100*100 pxs). then when we click on each user, we would go to the main user page which is showing the image larger(300*300 pxs). my images quality are not high because I resized them with 'image intervention' package. but still google tell me more optimization needed in each page

Comment: mokhatry it could be that the image file size is huge which causes the page to load slower.. but then again what did google analytics exactly say?

Comment: forexample one of my image size is 30kb, when I download the optimized version from 'google insight' it is same dimension and file size is 13kb. how is this possible? how does the google optimize the images? how should I do that?

Comment: 17kb isn't that big of a difference.. a big difference would be a file size getting reduced from 1mb to 500kb or something along those lines.. so unless you are serving huge files this shouldn't be a problem just because google says so

Comment: @flex_ would you please check this address, it is showing my website optimizations. my delay was for an update in optimizing but still my site rank is poor. how should I go through image optimization the same as google do it? https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.itutorialist.com%2F&tab=desktop

Comment: google has packages for their image optimizer which can be installed on your web server (nginx or apache) there are packages for both. apache:https://modpagespeed.com/doc/download nginx:https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed i have visited ur website and honestly it's pretty fast.. so idk if there is much to optimize

Answer (score 3):

Image optimization is not only about image resizing, there are a couple of elements that impact image file size:

1. **Image quality** - In most cases, you can significantly lower quality without a significant visual impact. Consider your image purpose and audience, and use the lowest possible quality that is acceptable for the image content, audience, and purpose.
2. **Image format** - Make sure each image is delivered in the right format for its image content. Take advantage of CDN services or other tools/logic to check which browser is making the request and deliver different formats for different browsers using the  element and its srcset attribute.
3. **Image metadata** - By default, images contain a lot of metadata stored by cameras and graphics applications, but this data is completely unnecessary in delivered images.
4. **Image sizing and resizing** - Even when resizing on the server-side, keep in mind that you can crop to focus on important content, and not just scale down your images.

In my web design projects I use Cloudinary for [image optimization](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_optimization).

Basically, it can find the best quality compression level and optimal encoding settings based on the image content and the browser and to automate the trade-off decision between the file and the quality.

**Here is how I'm doing it:**

- optimize image quality with the "quality = auto" parameter:

  `cl_image_tag("sample.jpg", array("quality"=>"auto"))`

This will reduce the file size without any noticeable degradation to the human eye and without the need to individually analyze every image.

- optimize image format with the "fetch_format = auto parameter:

`cl_image_tag("sample.jpg", array("width"=>500, "fetch_format"=>"auto", "crop"=>"scale"))`

This will scale down to 500 pixels and deliver the image in JPEG format.

- optimize image size by cropping:

`cl_image_tag("sample.jpg", array("transformation"=>array(
  array("aspect_ratio"=>"4:3", "crop"=>"fill"),
  array("width"=>"auto", "dpr"=>"auto", "crop"=>"scale")
  )))`

Comment: Where is the code you posted run? As part of a build process, or as part of your application?

Answer (score 0):

from your question I understand that you don't need optimization you need "resize on the fly" service. I will show you how i am doing it.

1. [Download and install Intervention Image to Laravel](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)
2. [Download and install Intervention Image CACHE to Laravel](http://image.intervention.io/use/cache)

**After downloading the cache component don't read it's documention for now just install it with composer**

3. Open routes/web.php and create new route like this you can replace the name and modify it to fit your needs

```html
Route::get('resizer/{photo}/{ext}/{width}/{height}',function($photo, 
    $ext, $width,$height) {

    $image = new \Intervention\Image\ImageManager();
    $url = public_path('images/'.$photo.".".$ext); // If your photo is in public folder
    enter code here
    $res = $image->cache(function ($image) use ($url) {

        return $image->make($url)->resize($width, $height);
    }, 9999, true);

    return $res->response();

    })->name('resizer');
```

4. Then in your blade template you can use it like this

```html
<img src="{{route(resizer,[$photo,$ext,$width,$height])}}"/>
```

The process is pretty simple you fetch the photo pass it to intervention image then cache it for faster response and return it as response with correct headers. If you have any question ask !. Wish you luck

P.S You can run optimization on the image before the response if you want.
P.S1 You have to make additional check if the photo exists before processing **This is just Proof Of Concept how you can do it**

Comment: thanks alot for your reply. I have to say that I also am using the image intervention package and I have resized all my images before. but now in the google pagespeed i have image optimization issue.(https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/). and I need to solve the google pagespeed problem.